# Sort - Move numbers and special characters to the end

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort an array which looks like this:

```
var arr = ["a", "c", "1", "e", "-", "4", "p", "$", "~", "6", "33", "h"];
```

the order I want to get should be:

```
var arr = ["a", "c", "e", "h", "p", "-", "~", "$", "1", "33", "4", "6"];
```

I already have a working solution but I am not sure if this is the best (fastest) way how to do it.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    if (arr[i].localeCompare("a") >= 0) {
        if (i > 0) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, arr.splice(0, i));
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question fits best Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try benchmarking at jsperf.com

Comment: You simply need a `sort` callback function which returns `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on whether `a` should be sorted before, equal to or after `b`. You just need to update your comparison logic to consider your specific rules...

Comment: Is there specific ordering criteria for special characters and numbers as well ? Or you just need alphabets sorted in front, and rest of the stuff can be anything after it.

Comment: @DhruvPathak I can try make a benchmark ,but I am also curious whether there are some other ways how to do it. Edit: All characters should be ordered by `localeCompare` I don't need any "special/specific logic"

Comment: @deceze well that's not the problem.

Comment: Must the letters be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: @Jack: of course and numbers as well. I mean `"1", "33", "4", "6"`

Comment: @0101 Sorry, how exactly is that not the problem?

Comment: @deceze probably not at all. I understand how the `sort` works and what a sort callback should return. I am basically asking what I should do, what is the fastest way how to do sorting described above...

Comment: As I said (and as @Bergi answered): make your comparison callback return an appropriate response, instead of "fixing" the order after the fact.

Comment: I did it like this on purpose. I have not done any benchmarks ,but I guess that is should be faster than solution where is everything inside a sort callback ,but maybe I am wrong. I'll try to do some benchmark...

Comment: Bergi's solution traverses the array once (or well, does one sort iteration), yours does one sort + one more iteration. The number of `localeCompare` invocations is different, if anything the difference is there and depends on how performant that function is vs. the overhead of another iteration.

Comment: @deceze the for loop will not do one whole iteration. If there are only ten special characters it will iterate only through ten items (Special characters are at the beginning after sort) and the sort logic where is a lot more iterations is simplier-faster than Bergi's one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should include the logic in the comparison function. This will be easier to understand than first sorting by one criteria and then shifting around parts of the array by some other criteria, and it will be reusable in other situations.

You want

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aIsAlphabetical = a.localeCompare("a") >= 0,
        bIsAlphabetical = b.localeCompare("a") >= 0;
    if (!aIsAlphabetical && bIsAlphabetical)
        return 1;
    if (aIsAlphabetical && !bIsAlphabetical)
        return -1;
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

or, shortened:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (b.localeCompare("a")>=0)-(a.localeCompare("a")>=0) || a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

If you're looking for fastest code, you should set up a benchmark at the targetted system with a good example array.

Comment: To add, keep in mind that arrays are sorted in place, so make sure to always clone the array when running a benchmark.

Comment: Looks good ,but I did a benchmark on a specific platform and to sort an array with 1335 items it take about ~1336.75ms (Yes I know, slow) ,but with my version that is above it take ~502.75ms which is a big difference.